# JavaScript & JSP Text Fields Won't Clear

Tags: html, jsp

I've found many examples online on how to clear the same text field you click on, but I'd like the user to click on text field 1 and it clear text field 2, and vice versa.

Been struggling on this for hours. The problem I'm having is I'm having no errors, no output, and it doesn't work. I have no idea what the problem is.

My code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="speed" class="java.lang.String" scope="request" />
<jsp:useBean id="force" class="java.lang.String" scope="request" />

<script>
    function clearSpeed() {
        var x = document.getElementByID(speed);
        x.value = "";
    }

    function clearForce() {
        var x = document.getElementByID(force);
        x.value = "";
    }
</script>

<input type="text" id="speed" onfocus='clearForce()' value="<%=speed%>">

<input type="text" id="force" onfocus='clearSpeed()' value="<%=force%>">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote your strings, and JavaScript is case-sensitive - the function is [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) :

```
function clearSpeed() {
    var x = document.getElementById('speed'); // added quotes around the id
    x.value = "";
}

function clearForce() {
    var x = document.getElementById('force'); // added quotes around the id
    x.value = "";
}
```

Better would be this :

```
<input type="text" id="speed" onfocus="clearValue('force')" value="<%=speed%>">
<input type="text" id="force" onfocus="clearValue('speed')" value="<%=force%>">
```

Calls a single function (I also changed the quotes round for better consistency)

Updated JavaScript:

```
function clearValue(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id); // no need for quotes and value passed in as variable
    x.value = "";
}
```

This promotes re-usable code and less duplication

```
var x = document.getElementById(id);
x.value = "";
```

could become (if you really wanted to make it shorter !)

```
document.getElementById(id).value = "";
```

There is no need to use a variable, unless of course you want to do other things with the DOM element

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. I'm doing this inside Liferay so there might be some other problems I'm not considering. I've tried a few different browsers and still no luck.

Thanks for the swift reply though it's appreciated! :)

Comment: @KenReid if all you had was the code above then my updates would fix the problems - but it seems your problems are a little wider - check the Server Logs and browser JavaScript console for any errors. Using something like [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) might help you diagnose the problems

Comment: Huh, so changing to the new edit you put above (the document.getELementByID(id).value="";), it now works. I'm not entirely sure how that's different that the previos one (I realize it's more efficient) but not sure why it makes it work! Anyway, thanks alot, I spent hours on this now. Very grateful!

Comment: @KenReid note the case sensitive function names in JavaScript - its `getElementById` not `getElementByID`